# Opening a file with multiple objects

Tags: c#, file-io, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to open and display a file that has multiple objects in it (array). I am able to open a file and display only the first object inside the file, but I want to be able to open and display **all** the object inside the file.

Here is how I tried it:

```
public T BinaryFileDeSerialize<T>(string filePath)
        {
            FileStream fileStream = null;
            Object obj;
            try
            {
                if (!File.Exists(filePath))
                    throw new FileNotFoundException("The file" + " was not found. ", filePath);
                fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);
                BinaryFormatter b = new BinaryFormatter(); obj = b.Deserialize(fileStream);
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (fileStream != null)
                    fileStream.Close();
            }
            return (T)obj;
        }
```

`MainForm`:

```
 private Animal ReadFile(string filename)
        {
            BinSerializerUtility BinSerial = new BinSerializerUtility();
            Animal str = BinSerial.BinaryFileDeSerialize<Animal>(filename);
            return str;
        }


  private void mnuFileOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string thefilename = openFileDialog1.FileName;

                    Animal msg = ReadFile(thefilename);

                    if (msg != null)
                    {
                        Resultlst.Items.Add(msg);
                    }
                    else
                        UpdateResults();
                }
        }
```

I'm not getting any error. The problem is that it opens and display only the first object in the file. I want it to open and display **all** the objects in that file.

**UPDATE:**

This is how I Serialized it:

```
    public void BinaryFileSerialize(object[] objs, string filePath)
            {
                FileStream fileStream = null;
                try
                {
                    fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
                    BinaryFormatter b = new BinaryFormatter();
                    foreach (var obj in objs)
                    {
                        b.Serialize(fileStream, obj);
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    throw;
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (fileStream != null)
                        fileStream.Close();
                }

            }
```

**UPDATE 2:**

```
public T BinaryFileDeSerialize<T>(string filePath)
        {
            FileStream fileStream = null;
            Object obj;

            if (!File.Exists(filePath))
                throw new FileNotFoundException("The file" + " was not found. ", filePath);

            using (var thefileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
            {
                BinaryFormatter b = new BinaryFormatter();
                obj = b.Deserialize(thefileStream);
            }

            return (T)obj;
        }



    private Animal[] ReadFile(string filename)
        {
            BinSerializerUtility BinSerial = new BinSerializerUtility();
            var animals = BinSerial.BinaryFileDeSerialize<Animal[]>(filename);
            return animals;
        }


    private void mnuFileOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string thefilename = openFileDialog1.FileName;

                    Animal []msg = ReadFile(thefilename);

                    if (msg != null)
                    {
                        Resultlst.Items.Add(msg);
                    }
                    else
                        UpdateResults();
                }
```

I'm getting error:

> Failed to convert an object of type Namespace.Animal to type
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1 [Namespace.Animal].

The error comes from this `return (T)obj;`

Comment: You try to deserialize only one object(Animal), also I can not understand about the for loop????? You do the same job in loop body

Comment: I removed the for loop. 
How can I deserialize the amount of object that the file includes?

Comment: It depends on your binary file, I don't have any idea how do you serialize object. Maybe instead of cast to object try to cast to list

Comment: You can use the code in my answer, that should be working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the current serializer you should change deserialize methos as follow:

```
public IList<T> BinaryFileDeSerialize<T>(string filePath) where T: class
{
    var list = new List<T>();

    if (!File.Exists(filePath))
       throw new FileNotFoundException("The file" + " was not found. ", filePath);
    using(var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
    {
          BinaryFormatter b = new BinaryFormatter(); 

          while(fileStream.Position < fileStream.Length)
             list.Add((T)b.Deserialize(fileStream));
    }                     

    return list;
}
```

And ReadFile should be like this:

```
 private Animal[] ReadFile(string filename)
 {
        BinSerializerUtility BinSerial = new BinSerializerUtility();
        var animals = BinSerial.BinaryFileDeSerialize<Animal>(filename);

        return animals.ToArray();
 }


 private void mnuFileOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
      string thefilename = openFileDialog1.FileName;
      var messages = ReadFile(thefilename);

      if (messages != null)
      {
          messages.ToList().ForEach(msg => 
                Resultlst.Items.Add(msg));
      }
      else
      {
         UpdateResults();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: the `list.Add(b.Deserialize(fileStream));` had invalid arguments. Also what is `obj`?

Comment: And how should the `fileOpenDialog_click` event handler look like?

I tried it like this: `Animal []msg = ReadFile(thefilename);`

Answer (score 0):

Silly question, but what happens if you serialize as `List<Animal>` then try to call `BinaryFileDeSerialize<List<Animal>>()`?

Also, you can simplify your method thusly with a using statement.

```
    public T BinaryFileDeSerialize<T>(string filePath)
    {
        FileStream fileStream = null;
        Object obj;

        if (!File.Exists(filePath))
            throw new FileNotFoundException("The file" + " was not found. ", filePath);

        using(var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
        {
           BinaryFormatter b = new BinaryFormatter(); 
           obj = b.Deserialize(fileStream);
        }

        return (T)obj;
    }
```

EDIT:

Try these tweaks to your code...

```
    //call via BinaryFileSerialize<Animal>(..., ...);

    public void BinaryFileSerialize<T>(T[] objs, string filePath)
    {
            using(var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
              BinaryFormatter b = new BinaryFormatter();
              b.Serialize(fileStream, objs);
            }
    }


    private Animal[] ReadFile(string filename)
    {
        BinSerializerUtility BinSerial = new BinSerializerUtility();
        var animals = BinSerial.BinaryFileDeSerialize<Animal[]>(filename);
        return animals;
    }
```

Comment: It can't convert a class type to list. How do I make this a list?  `return (T)obj;`

Comment: T is just the type. "Animal" is a type and "List<Animal>" is also a type (a generic List of Animals), the call "BinaryFileDeSerialize<List<Animal>>()" is what you'd do. Your serialization code can serialize as "List<Animal>", then your deserialization code might work if you use the line: _var str = BinSerial.BinaryFileDeSerialize<List<Animal>>(filename);_

Comment: But why are you showing `BinaryFileSerialize` method? I'm trying to open a file, not create it.

Comment: Can you show me how the `BinaryFileDeSerialize` method would look like?

Comment: To demonstrate that you want to make sure that you're serializing and deserializing using identical types (in this case, saving an Animal array and loading an Animal array from the saved file).

Comment: The BinaryFileDeSerialize would look like it does in the first part of my answer.